# AsciidocFX — Specify a separate folder for output (generated files for PDF, EPUB, HTML, etc.)

Tags: files-folders, asciidocfx, asciidoc

When writing books in [Asciidoc](https://asciidoc.org/) format, the author occasionally generates a rendering. For example, the author may create files in [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF), [EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB), or [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) format.

In the [AsciidocFX](https://asciidocfx.com/) app, the default location for generated output is the same folder storing the source code files of the book.

Some problems with mixing output files with the input files:

- Confusion. When writing, the author wants to see only the inputs.
- Safety. The output files are disposable while the inputs are not.
- File space. Backup systems such as [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(macOS)) on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) make copies of all the files in the book folders, both inputs and outputs. But the outputs, being disposable, are a waste of space in the backup volume.

Is there any way in AsciidocFX to specify a different folder for outputs?